# Bit scan forward and reverse in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, binary, bitboard

I need to count the number of trailing and leading zeros in a numpy uint64 variable, so right now I'm doing it like this:

```
# n > 0
n = np.uint64(100)
s = np.binary_repr(n)
trail_zeros = len(s) - len(s.rstrip('0'))
lead_zeros = 64 - len(s)
```

Is there a better way of doing this, without using strings?
The priority is speed. Thank you!

Comment: `trail_zeros = 63-lead_zeros-s.rfind('1')` seems to be a little faster than your solution, still strings tho

Comment: What should it return if `n = np.uint64(0)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For numbers in `[0,2**63)`, we can use some arithmetic operations to get the leading and trailing zeros in their binary formats and hence skip the string manipulations -

```
def get_leading_trailing_zeros(n):
    a = (2**np.arange(64) & n)
    lead_zeros = 64-a.argmax()-1
    if n==0:
        trail_zeros = 1
    else:
        trail_zeros = (a==0).argmin()
    return lead_zeros,trail_zeros
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the speed of the following code. But you can certainly do it like this, without using strings.

```
n = np.uint64(100)
i=1
while((n>>np.uint64(i))%2==0):
    i+=1

trail_zeros=i
```

You right shift the value `n` until you get an odd number. Number of right shifts done is equal to `trail_zeros`.

Comment: I think this answer is easier to vectorize and has lower memory foot print and better performance than the accepted answer of @Divakar.

Answer (score 1):

```
lead_zeros = int(64-np.ceil(np.log2(n)))
```

Because `len(s)` is equal to `ceil(log2(n))`. This is pure arithmetic operation so it can be perfectly vectorized by numpy and much faster than writing your own loop.

## Performance

[image: performance_lead_zeros]

Comment: This fails for `n = np.uint64(0)`.